# all my individual wordpress pages are redirecting to xampp default page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, xampp, html

I'm just trying to access the individual wordpress pages like about, member login, registration etc and for any individual page i get redirected to the localhosts(in this case xampp) home page.  Here is my log file:

```
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:50:25 -0700] "GET /localpressjuicery/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/wordpress/wp-content.css?ver=4.1.1&wp-mce-4107-20150118 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
```

::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:50:25 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4360 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:50:37 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:50:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:52:37 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:52:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:54:37 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:54:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:56:37 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:56:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 135 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:58:37 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:11:58:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:12:00:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:12:02:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 135 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:12:04:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1429470280.8353641033172607421875 HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "WordPress/4.1.1; http://localhost/localpressjuicery"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:12:04:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:12:06:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
::1 - - [19/Apr/2015:12:08:40 -0700] "POST /localpressjuicery/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 135 "http://localhost/localpressjuicery/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"

Comment: Show some logs at least. Any answers will just be guesswork with the information you've given.

Comment: where do i get the logs?

Comment: '\xampp\apache\logs\', possibly?

Comment: k i posted the log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you haven't updated your WordPress General Settings.

Log into phpMyAdmin and select your database. Go to the options table and update **siteurl** and **home** rows.

[image: screenshot]

You can also so this by logging into your WordPress admin area and navigating to general settings. However, I doubt you can access your admin area.

Comment: odly enough i can access my admin area.  So how can i do so via admin?

Comment: nvm i got it...i had these lines in the wp config file:  define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/localpressjuicery/') and define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/localpressjuicery/') and changed the url in database like you said.

Comment: I will probably redirect. Anywho, you should go to Settings >> General

Comment: ok you know what it still did not solve the problem...i have those two lines above commentted out and still did not solve the problem.